# How to get string from pointer

Tags: winapi

```
GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndFoundWindow, &dwTrayProcessID);
HANDLE  hTrayProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, dwTrayProcessID);
int iButtonsCount = SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);
LPVOID  lpData = VirtualAllocEx(hTrayProc, NULL, sizeof(TBBUTTON), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
int         iButton;
DWORD       dwBytesRead;
TBBUTTON   buttonData;

dwBytesRead = -1;
int chk_data = (int)SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_GETBUTTON, iButton, (LPARAM)lpData);
ReadProcessMemory(hTrayProc, lpData, &buttonData, sizeof(TBBUTTON), &dwBytesRead);

int len_text = (int)SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, buttonData.idCommand, (LPARAM)lpData);
```

till now, i know the length of button's text but i also need to get the text to display on console.
my problem is i do not really know how to get that text from the button. please kindly help.

what i am trying is ... trying to access to lpData to get the string inside, but could not do that.

Comment: If the buffer is `'\0'` terminated, then you can use `strcpy` to copy the buffer contents to some string.

Comment: Your code is incomplete however it is clearly wrong. You have not shown the code that calls VirtualAlloc to allocate memory in the other process. Did you do that? Your code gets it all wrong. You ask for a null-terminated string but then try to read it into a TBBUTTON. You should show an SSCCE.

Comment: I wrote this: LPVOID lpData = VirtualAllocEx(hTrayProc, NULL, sizeof(TBBUTTON), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);

Comment: You need to take my comments much more seriously. Here's what is needed in an edit to the question. 1. A clear statement of what you are attempting to do. 2. An SSCCE. 3. Details of how your attempts to solve problem fail.

Comment: now we know the length of button's string in len_text. after this, i also want to get "string" from the button.. how, please help ?

Comment: I do know how to do what I think you are attempting. But I absolutely won't help with the question in the state it is in now. You need to follow the steps I outlined in comments above to fix the question. You have to make more effort. This is a two way process. You need to do your part. You cannot hope to have questions answered until you can ask a proper question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. That's a little better. I've removed the language tags (again) because language is not relevant. And what's more, it cannot be both C and C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first comment is that you need to add error checking to your code. As far as I can see, you perform no checking of return values. Any of the API functions you call could fail. If you don't check return values for errors then you have no way of diagnosing where you went wrong.

For instance, starting with `GetWindowThreadProcessId`, you need to write it like this:

```
if (GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndFoundWindow, &dwTrayProcessID) == 0)
{
    // handle error
}
```

And so on for all the other functions. Consult MSDN carefully to understand how each function signals failure.

Now to the main part of the question. I believe that it is the `TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW` message that is giving you trouble. You need to write it like this:

```
LRESULT len = SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, 
    buttonData.idCommand, NULL);
if (len == -1)
{
    // handle error
}

size_t size = sizeof(wchar_t)*(len+1);

LPVOID lpData = VirtualAllocEx(hTrayProc, NULL, size, MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_READWRITE);
if (lpData == NULL)
{
    // handle error
}

len = SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, 
    buttonData.idCommand, (LPARAM)lpData);
if (len == -1)
{
    // handle error
}

wchar_t* str = new wchar_t[len+1];

if (!ReadProcessMemory(hTrayProc, lpData, (LPVOID)str, size, NULL))
{
    // handle error
}

// the text is now in str, as a null-terminated UTF-16 string

delete[] str;
```

Answer (score -1):

You need this: (see [documentation of TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

```
WCHAR *buffer ;
int len_text = (int)SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, 
                                buttonData.idCommand, (LPARAM)NULL); 

buffer = (WCHAR*)malloc(sizeof(WCHAR) * (len_text + 1)) ;
SendMessage(hwndFoundWindow, TB_GETBUTTONTEXTW, 
                                buttonData.idCommand, (LPARAM)buffer); 

....
free(buffer) ;
```

Comment: Look closely at the code. The memory is in a different process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I've seen that, but I was not sure that this is really relevant as we have very little information about the actual problem.

Comment: Asker is trying to read information from notification icons in the shell process. The giveaway is hTrayProc. Question is grossly incomplete. Asker needs to fix it.